# django custom login view (login as guest)

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

i am making an ecommerce and i have  a **checkout view** in that view  i have three  forms : a **login form**  a **guest login form** and a **billing address form**  so basically  if a user  is logged in  normally or as guest    i am displaying  the billing address form in the template 'checkout.html' otherwise   i  display the login form and the guest login form   but   these two forms are handled in  different  views  **checkout_login** and **guest_checkout_login**  so my question is : is it safe to do so  ?

this is the checkout template :

```
{% if not billing_profile %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login_page' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">

{{ form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>


<form method="post" action="{% url 'guest_login_page' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">

{{ guest_form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
{% else %}
<h1>checkout</h1>
billing profile:{{billing_profile}} </br>
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
{{ adress_form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

this is the chekout_login view:

```
def login_page(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    next_ = request.POST.get('next')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user     = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                if is_safe_url(next_, request.get_host()):
                    guest_email_id = request.session.get('guest_email_id')
                    if guest_email_id:
                        del request.session['guest_email_id']
                    return redirect(next_)
                else:
                    return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return redirect("/")
```

if  i am doing any mistake please tell me

Comment: what is the problem just include the problem

Comment: @Pavankumar  well the problem is that a user  can inspect the page and see the url that handles the form  and then go to that url so  is it safe  to show the url that handle the form ??